revalidate("articles") in nextjs 14 App router (Is it update all aticles in nextjs cache)?
I have multiple articles in cms and i have update or articles in cms backend. In nextjs listing page i want to show list of articles. I have use fetchQuery in for articles and pass tag: ["articles"] then revalidate in api routes files like this revalidate("articles") Is it update all articles in cache or update only one articles?
